# Get concrete error message of CouldNotSaveException

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, exception, adobe-commerce

We need to get concrete error message when **Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository** throws **CouldNotSaveException** during `saveProduct()`

```
private function saveProduct($product): void
{
    try {
        $this->removeProductFromLocalCacheBySku($product->getSku());
        $this->removeProductFromLocalCacheById($product->getId());
        $this->resourceModel->save($product);
    } catch (ConnectionException $exception) {
...
    } catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new CouldNotSaveException(
            __('The product was unable to be saved. Please try again.'),
            $e
        );
    }
}
```

An easy way would be just adding the message in that code

```
__('The product was unable to be saved. Please try again.' . $e->getMessage())
```

But we can't edit that file, as this is a project hosted in Adobe Cloud. So, how can we get that message instead of application default message?

Comment: I'd recommend syncing down a copy of your production database, etc. locally to try to replicate the issue. At that point, you can either modify the local code for testing, or try to trigger a breakpoint at that location with Xdebug.

Comment: Sure. But I would like to find a way to get the error in production logs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**1. Create Plugin for `ProductRepositoryInterface`**

In example also creates additional logger to write exception to separate file

`app/code/Acme/StackExchange/etc/di.xml`

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <!-- Create Virtual Logger -->
    <virtualType name="Acme\StackExchange\Model\VirtualLoggerHandler" type="Magento\Framework\Logger\Handler\Base">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="fileName" xsi:type="string">/var/log/acme_stackexchange.log</argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <virtualType name="Acme\StackExchange\Model\VirtualLogger" type="Magento\Framework\Logger\Monolog">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="handlers" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="system" xsi:type="object">Acme\StackExchange\Model\VirtualLoggerHandler</item>
            </argument>
        </arguments>
    </virtualType>
    <!-- Register Plugin -->
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface">
        <plugin name="Acme_StackExchange_Plugin_Catalog_Model_ProductRepositoryPlugin"
                type="Acme\StackExchange\Plugin\Catalog\Model\ProductRepositoryPlugin" sortOrder="10"/>
    </type>
    <!-- Pass Virtual Logger to Plugin -->
    <type name="Acme\StackExchange\Plugin\Catalog\Model\ProductRepositoryPlugin">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="logger" xsi:type="object">Acme\StackExchange\Model\VirtualLogger</argument>
        </arguments>
    </type>
</config>
```

**2. Create a Plugin**

`app/code/Acme/StackExchange/Plugin/Catalog/Model/ProductRepositoryPlugin.php`

```php
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Acme\StackExchange\Plugin\Catalog\Model;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\Data\ProductInterface;
use Magento\Catalog\Api\ProductRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\CouldNotSaveException;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

class ProductRepositoryPlugin
{
    protected LoggerInterface $logger;

    public function __construct(
        LoggerInterface $logger
    ) {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function aroundSave(
        ProductRepositoryInterface $subject,
        callable $proceed,
        ProductInterface $product,
        $saveOptions = false
    ): ProductInterface {
        try {
            return $proceed($product, $saveOptions);
        } catch (CouldNotSaveException $e) {
            if ($e->getPrevious()) {
                $this->logger->critical($e->getPrevious());
            }
            throw $e;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: We can not use a plugin, or interceptor because saveProduct() is the private method (Non-public methods).

Comment: @Msquare I suggest to attentively read provided solution again or just test it )

Comment: @Raul Sanchez In my example instead of log message you can throw new Exception, and I recommend to use `CouldNotSaveException` instance for this. `$e->getPrevious()` is original one exception, that you can use for generate your custom exception message and receive original error.

Comment: Nice! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Patch is the way to go, we use https://github.com/cweagans/composer-patches.

```
composer require cweagans/composer-patches
```

General flow is this:

1. Create a copy of original file, edit the file, create a patch file using `diff` command. Patches are relative to package folder:

   ```
   cd vendor/magento/module-catalog
   cp Model/ProductRepository.php Model/ProductRepository.orig.php
   # Edit Model/ProductRepository.php with your changes...
   mkdir ../../../patches
   diff -u Model/ProductRepository.orig.php Model/ProductRepository.php > ../../../patches/Magento_Catalog-save-product-original-exception.patch
   ```

   In my example it looks like this:

   ```
   --- Model/ProductRepository.orig.php    2022-07-18 10:35:56.200056524 +0300
   +++ Model/ProductRepository.php 2022-07-18 10:37:34.022779326 +0300
   @@ -909,7 +909,7 @@
                throw $e;
            } catch (\Exception $e) {
                throw new CouldNotSaveException(
   -                __('The product was unable to be saved. Please try again.'),
   +                __('The product was unable to be saved. Please try again. ' . $e->getMessage()),
                    $e
                );
            }
   ```
2. Place your patch in project folder or to public URL. patches/ local folder in this example.
3. Register patch in composer.json

   ```json
   {
       "extra": {
           "magento-force": "override",
           "composer-exit-on-patch-failure": true,
           "patches": {
               "magento/module-catalog": {
                   "Original exception message in product save": "patches/Magento_Catalog-save-product-original-exception.patch"
               }
           },
       }
   }
   ```
4. Do `composer install`

[image: composer install - applying patch]

Our collection of patches - https://github.com/ConvertGroupsAS/magento2-patches

Comment: This is good solution for handle patches and make sense to use in some cases, but Magento Cloud has own patch system and you can just place this patch into `m2-hotfixes` directory. Can you explain me, why everybody try to suggest the option with overwrite original core class instead of use disigned plugin system? Any private and protected methods are call from some public and available to cover public with plugin.

Comment: @VictorTihonchuk I already upvoted your solution with accessing original exception in plugin in this case ;) With everything could be fixed without patching, alas often it's not the case for Magento :) Plugin here has benefit of not relying on specific line numbers that will change with future Magento versions.
As for m2-hotfixes, some patches are reusable across projects where not all of them are on cloud, so sometimes it's natural to have non-cloud patching solution.

Comment: The major reason of my comment under your answer was point that Magento Cloud has own patch system https://devdocs.magento.com/cloud/project/project-patch.html. I'm totally agree with logic to share patches between project. I have some number of general fixes for 2.4.4 (core bugs) and some for add PHP 8.1 support for 3rd party extensions.

Comment: Thanks. I will give this a try, but I have accepted Victor answer, as it fits more in this case